# Set slaves for jupyterq

Tags: jupyter, kdb

I am running Q in jupyter. To enable multiple slaves, jupyter requires to be run with parameter `-s`.

How can I launch a kernel in jupyerq with slaves enabled?
I tried passing `-s 20` into argv here in `runkernel.py`, but the kernel wouldn't start at all

```
os.execvp('/bin/qlib/3.6.x86_64/q', ['/bin/qlib/3.6.x86_64/q', jupyterq_kernel.q', '-cds'] + argv)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

1. Find the location of your `kernel.json` file for qpk by running

```
$jupyter kernelspec list
  qpk        /Users/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/qpk
```

Open the `kernel.json` file and modify the following line as outlined to set up the notebook to initialise 20 slaves threads on server startup

```
 "env": {"JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS":"","MPLBACKEND":"Agg"}

Changed to 

"env": {"JUPYTERQ_SERVERARGS":"-s 20","MPLBACKEND":"Agg"}
```

For reference instructions for completing command line argument execution for jupyterq can be found here:
https://code.kx.com/v2/ml/jupyterq/notebooks/#server-command-line-arguments